# Pandas: How to CHECK if all rows in a dataframe add up to 100 for TWO columns only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just wondering, how I would check if all rows in my dataframe add up to 100 for two columns only?

For example, check out a sample of my data below:

```
ID   STUDENT_NAME     PART_1_SCORE     PART_2_SCORE     GRADE
--------------------------------------------------------------
1    John Smith       50               50               A+
2    Andy Peters      30               70               B
3    Sally David      70               30               C
4    Bev Jones        20               80               E
5    Tom Wood         10               80               B
```

Now, how would I check that the "PART_1_SCORE" and "PART_2_SCORE" all add up to 100 for all the rows in my data? Hence, this is a sample of 5 rows, but my actual data has over 1,000 rows - so what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks - any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df["PART_1_SCORE"] + df["PART_2_SCORE"]).eq(100).all()
```

will return `True` if all rows are equal to 100 and `False` otherwise.

Now, you might want which rows do not comply.

```
df.loc[(df["PART_1_SCORE"] + df["PART_2_SCORE"]).ne(100)]
```

which will locate all rows for which the sum of the columns isn't 100.

Comment: Hi - tried your solution, but it keeps giving me False. Just so you know, my values are floats. Is this what is causing it?

Comment: If the values are like `100` and `100.0`, it shouldn't be an issue, it will still output `True`. What does the second line outputs ? Which rows does it print ?

Comment: Thanks - it was 100.00. Also, for the rows that do not comply, how would I drop them all or filter them all out? Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it happens now worries, you can use `eq` instead of `ne` in the second line and set that to a new dataframe.

`clean = df.loc[(df["PART_1_SCORE"] + df["PART_2_SCORE"]).eq(100)]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I really appreciate it so, so much!

Comment: No problem, take care

Comment: Hey - I tried this with 3 columns instead of 2, and it is giving me the wrong results. What is causing this? I just used this: df.loc[(df["PART_1_SCORE"] + df["PART_2_SCORE"] + df["PART_3_SCORE"]).ne(100)]

Comment: This outputs the rows for which the sum is not 100, doesn't that work?

Comment: No, it seems to be returning a mix of rows where the sum of the three columns is 100.

Comment: Without seeing data and code, it's difficult to answer. You could probably open a new question. You could also select the three columns and use the sum method then the not equal method and check that

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to get what you need. First, make sure your columns you want to sum up are floats:

```
score_cols = ['PART_1_SCORE','PART_2_SCORE']
for col in score_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

Then, create a new column with their sum

```
df['total_score'] = df['PART_1_SCORE'] + df['PART_2_SCORE']
```

And then you can check whether they all sum up:

```
# Way number 1: count the results that are less than 100
len(df[df['total_score'] < 100]) # should be 0 if they all sum up to 100.

# Way number 2:  create a new dataframe with the ones that don't sum up to a 100:
less_df = df[df['total_score'] < 100]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution too!

Comment: I would, but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry!